# Why is my postfix running as relay?

Tags: postfix, smtp, email-server

OK, so this is hugely embarrassing:

A while ago I set up a server and installed postfix to send email.

Now I have implemented SPF, DMARC and DKIM (using Mailgun for everything else except this one server - or so I thought) and was expecting my emails coming from the server to be rejected. However, they were not, and upon inspecting the headers they are passing through Mailgun's infrastructure, e.g.:

```
Received: from server1.example.com (server1.example.com [x.x.x.x]) by mxa.mailgun.org with ESMTP id ***; Tue, 28 Feb 2017 11:18:07 -0000 (UTC)
Received: by server1.example.com (Postfix, from userid 1000) id ***; Tue, 28 Feb 2017 11:18:06 +0000 (GMT)
```

I've sent this email using this command:

```
$ echo "This is the body of the email" | mail  -s "This is the subject line" you@example.com
```

And this is my log:

```
$ tail /var/log/mail.log
Feb 28 11:18:06 server1 postfix/pickup[14836]: ***: uid=1000 from=<me>
Feb 28 11:18:06 server1 postfix/cleanup[14838]: ***: message-id=<20170228111806.***@server1.example.com>
Feb 28 11:18:06 server1 postfix/qmgr[14837]: ***: from=<me@example.com>, size=372, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Feb 28 11:18:07 server1 postfix/smtp[14840]: ***: to=<you@example.com>, relay=mxb.mailgun.org[54.89.39.203]:25, delay=0.97, delays=0/0/0.3/0.67, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 Great success)
Feb 28 11:18:07 server1 postfix/qmgr[14837]: ***: removed
```

The only logical explanation I have is that I somehow managed to set up postfix to work as a relay, but I've gone through the `/etc/postfix` dir and cannot find any hint, nor do I recall setting this up.

Here is my `/etc/postfix/main.cf` file (I removed all empty lines and comments):

```
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no
append_dot_mydomain = no
readme_directory = no
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = server1.example.com
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.example.com, localhost
relayhost =
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = loopback-only
inet_protocols = all
home_mailbox = Maildir/
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
```

Can someone point me to what I am missing? Why is postfix relaying mail through Mailgun? I'm just running out of ideas were to look.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, ouch! Just ouch! It was doing this because I sent to an email at my own domain! Thus mailgun's servers are the MX servers for the recipient, so it's sending there. I wish I could delete this question as it's way too embarrassing...

Comment: No worries, noone knows who you are anyway ;)